# Can't load flash code into page with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, flash

I am trying to load some flash banner code (from database) into a webpage using jquery ajax.

It is all working when adding the flash code in code-behind but when I am trying to load it with ajax some flash banners make the complete website disappear and only shows the banner.

I am using jQuery Ajax and the response is in html like:

```
<div id="ads">
  <object ... Flash code ... </object>
</div>
```

I am using `.html()` to add it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is the call you are making via Ajax on the same server? Ajax does not allow for crossdomain calls, can you provide a bit more information so we can help!

ie: Call is coming from yourdomain.com and going to anotherdomain.com/mydatafeed.xml